# Content type hub syndication

Tags: content-type, content-type-hub

I have created a site collection "Content type Hub" and created inside it all the site columns and content types I need.

I then accessed the `Settings -> Manage farm feature` to enable the syndication but I couldn't find it there. Is there a reason for that?

I couldn't find any information related to this

Answer (score 0):

Did you activate the "Content Type Syndication Hub" in the Site Collection features?  The hub syndicates across sites and site collections, but the feature has to be activated on that specific SC.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to do the following:**

- Go to the Root Site Settings > Below Site Collection Administration > Click on Site Collection Features.
- Check  `Content Type Syndication Hub Feature` > Activate.

**Check the details at**

- **[Missing Content Type Syndication Hub feature in SharePoint](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/configure-content-type-hub-in-sharepoint-2019/#missing-content-type-syndication-hub-feature)**
- **[Configure Content Type Hub in SharePoint 2019](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/configure-content-type-hub-in-sharepoint-2019/)**